# Can't Change Focus from Youtube IFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I have a [Youtube iFrame](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and I control playback using keyboard shortcuts. However, when I fast-forward/rewind, the focus changes to the iFrame, which captures subsequent key presses. Thus, I use a simple function to poll when focus changes to the iFrame, and then switch the focus back to the document body. Here is the live code:

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPbVow?editors=101)

However, it doesn't work! Even though `document.body.focus()` is being called, the focus never changes from the iFrame. Any idea how to fix this?

Note: The browser I'm using is **Chrome 41.0.2272.118 on my Surface Pro 3 (Win 8.1)**

Comment: really? you can fast forward twice? Mine fast forwards once and then any subsequent right-arrow presses just scrubs the video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem's like `focus()` only works on buttons (tested on `document.body` and regular `<p>` elements, both do nothing).

[Fixed CODEPEN (old, see update below!)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJwzRv?editors=101)

Note that I added `document.getElementById("btn").focus()` before `document.body.focus()`, yet the focus switches to `btn` and not `document.body`. The browser I'm using is Chrome 41.0.2272.118 on my Surface Pro 3 (Win 8.1)

### UPDATE

Turns out, if the button is hidden using `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`, the `focus()` method doesn't work anymore! This made me suspect that the issue was actually with whether or not an element is focusable or not. Apparently a `tabindex` of `-1` makes an element focusable, so I tested this by setting `document.body.tabIndex = -1;` before calling `document.body.focus()`. and lo and behold, IT WORKS!

[updated CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJwzOb?editors=101)